# Regex check if all key occurrences always have the same value

Tags: regex

Is there a way to check if all key occurrences have the same value?

I am looking for all state running values, but if a container returns a different value (for example "stopped" then return false to the entire regex

```
{"container-1":{"type":"info","state":"running","started_at":"2022-03-02T21:19:44.042239675Z"},"container-2":{"type":"info","state":"running","started_at":"2022-03-02T21:19:45.451556078Z"},"container-3":{"type":"info","state":"running","started_at":"2022-03-02T21:19:45.21944115Z"}
```

I alredy filtered the state: running with [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/YI0J0z/1) but how to do the validation to ensure that all the keys match the value "running"

```
"([^"]+?)"state"\s*:"running"
```

Comment: Don't use regexp to process JSON. Parse the JSON to an object and then check whether the result satisfies your conditions.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do what you want with regular expressions. You could match all the repetitions of the same value, but there's no way to test if all the keys have the same value.

Comment: I am using elastic monitor http check heartbeat for that reason I am using the regex expression https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/heartbeat/current/monitor-http-options.html

Comment: There might be a complicated way to do it with negative lookaheads, but I'm not sure.

Comment: If you just want to test if there's a state other than running, you could use `"state"\s*:(?!"running")`

Comment: Yes elastic uptime monitor http has an "Check response body does not contain" option, can you post it as an answer to mark as correct?

Comment: You should process the JSON with a JSON parser.  Regexes are not a magic wand that you wave at every problem that involves strings.

Comment: @AndyLester That was my first comment. He explained why he can't do that in this application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a way to use a regular expression to test if all the state values are the same.

But if there's a specific value you want to test, use a negative lookahead to reject anything else.

```
"state"\s*:(?!\s*"running")
```